# Change Font Settings in Windows using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

In windows machine, Do we have any way to enable the "**Allow fonts to be installed using a shortcut (advanced)**" option in **Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts\Font settings** using powershell script.

[Image of Font Settings Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8fGn.png)

Highlighted checkbox should be enabled

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Balakrishnan! Welcome to SO, SO is not a code writing site and this question isn't applicable here. Try editing your question to add more detail and more suitable for this site or try posting this on a different site! See [What shouldn't I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (-not (Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management"))
{
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management" -Force
}
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management" -Name "InstallAsLink" -PropertyType DWord -Value 1 -Force

Comment: Thanks a lot abactuon. It is working link a charm